# How to hide/remove the clock from the menu bar of Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

Here is the instruction to hide the clock from the menu bar.

https://ccm.net/faq/35096-ubuntu-hide-the-clock-from-the-menu-bar

```
Click on the Settings menu > System Settings.
Go to System > Time & Date
Click on the Clock tab
Uncheck Show a clock in the menu bar.
```

[image]

I wasn't sure which version of Ubuntu this article written for. But it was not for Ubuntu 20.04 as there is no option to uncheck `Show a clock in the menu bar` as shown in the screenshot/article above.

I just want to have top menu bar without the clock in the middle. That's it. Thanks

Comment: Note: Not available on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

I am also working on `ubuntu 20.04`.

Please install `gnome-tweaks`: `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-tweak-tool`. After that open the application `gnome-tweaks` and choose `top bar` from the left list, then you can customize your head bar.

This gives you opportunity to customize your `date` and `weekday`, but if you wants to remove the `clock` totally you would need to install further extensions, see if https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1110/hide-clock/ helps.

Comment: Thanks @Simon. I already have `gnome-tweaks` installed, but there is no option to remove/hide the clock. Can you share your findings?

Comment: @Wolf I may mistook your question, you want to remove the whole clock, right? I have updated the answer, hoping it helps.

Comment: In addition to what @Simon has shared, [this link](https://linuxconfig.org/install-gnome-shell-extensions-from-zip-file-using-command-line-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux) helped me to install & enable the plugin(as I'm not too well versed with my Ubuntu). Hope it helps some user like me :-)